# findViewById in Activity from Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

**Edit**: Damn, I just noticed the history resets everytime I go back to the main Activity from the fragment, so I can't see if the actions below actually work or not. I need to review my code.

---

The "coin2" onClick must append some text in the "history" TextView. "coin2" button is in the fragment while the "history" is in the MainActivity. I can't manage to access that TextView with findViewById, I read many solutions but none work, because inside the "case R.id.coin2" both history and rootView cannot be resolved. The CardBackFragment class is actually in the MainActivity.java file, not a separate file.

fragment.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/coin2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:text="@string/coin_button"
    android:onClick="flipcoin2" />
</LinearLayout>
```

fragment class:

```
public class CardBackFragment extends Fragment {


    public CardBackFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_coindice, container, false);
        v.findViewById(R.id.coin2).setOnClickListener(this);
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
        TextView history = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.history);
        return v;

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view){
        switch (view.getId())
        {
            case R.id.coin2:
                //history and rootView cannot be resolved.
                history = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.history);
                final String[] coin = {getString(R.string.head), getString(R.string.tail)};
                Random r = new Random();
                final int flip = r.nextInt(2);
                history.append("\n- " + getString(R.string.coin_message) + coin[flip]);

            break;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You cant access other view from another layout that would result to an exception, NPE.

**solution:**

either put your `textview`,`buttons` in your `fragment_main` xml so you can `findViewById` the textView or manually add the textView to your parent view programatically.

Take note dont inflate two layout in your fragment just **inflate 1** layout.

If the `textView` is inside the Activity.

you can call `getActivity().findViewById` directly from fragment:

**sample:**

```
    switch (view.getId())
    {
        case R.id.coin2:
            //history and rootView cannot be resolved.
            history = (TextView) CardBackFragment.this.getActivity().findViewById(R.id.history);
            final String[] coin = {getString(R.string.head), getString(R.string.tail)};
            Random r = new Random();
            final int flip = r.nextInt(2);
            history.append("\n- " + getString(R.string.coin_message) + coin[flip]);

        break;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with

```
    public class CardBackFragment extends Fragment {

public interface OnCoinClickedListener {
void onCoinClicked(String stringToAppend);
}

        public CardBackFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_coindice, container, false);
        }

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
mListener = (OnCoinClickedListener)activity;
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
mListener = null;
}
        @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View v, Bundle b) {
            v.findViewById(R.id.coin2).setOnClickListener(this);
    }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view){
            switch (view.getId())
            {
                case R.id.coin2:
                    final String[] coin = {getString(R.string.head), getString(R.string.tail)};
                    Random r = new Random();
                    final int flip = r.nextInt(2);
mListener.onCoinClicked("\n- " + getString(R.string.coin_message) + coin[flip]);
                break;
            }

        }
```

then, in your activity:

```
public class CoinActivity extends Activity implements OnCoinClickedListener{

private TextVIew mHistory;

[...] onCreate {
mHistory = (TextView)findviewById(R.id.history);
}

public void onCoinClicked(String s) {
mHistory.append(s);

}
```

Comment: The code doesn't give any errors but I get a NullPointerException when clicking "coin2".

Comment: check my edit, you need to make your activity implement the interface defined in the fragment. See [this](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html) for official info.